# How do I access Watson Assistant's global context

Tags: watson-assistant

If I send context to the Watson Assistant service with, [for example](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant)

```
{
    "global":{"system":{"user_id":"42"}},
    "skills":{"main skill":{"user_defined":{"account_number":"007"}}}
}
```

I can successfully refer to `account_number` in my Assistant dialog with `$account_number` or with `context.account_number`, [as documented](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language), but `$user_id` returns nothing.

How do I refer to Watson Assistant's global context variables?

Comment: After some further sleuthing, I see that I can do this with `<? context.metadata.user_id  ?>`, but it's not clear this is the correct approach, or where this is documented.

Comment: Looking at the json fields, this looks to be the response from the v2 message API call. You will find that "user_defined" json objects can be manipulated, read, etc. All other context elements are set and utilised by IBM. They will also state that these values are not guaranteed, and should be used with care.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the user_id field to your Assistant allows you to enable User metrics:

```
"context": {
  "global": {
    "system": {
      "user_id": "{UserID}"
    }
  }
}
```

(thats API v2 as v1 is slightly different)

As you later found out, the user_id fields will be then used for User metrics, and can be a referred as

```
<? context.metadata.user_id ?>
```

You can use that code and assign it to $user_id on Assistant.

More information can be found at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-logs-resources#logs-resources-user-id